# Before and After "Nav" Images

Tags: css, image, navigation, styles

I am having a bit of a brain fart. I need to slice this image into three parts, placing the ends at the left and right of a navigation div ("nav") respectively. For some reason, I cannot remember a semantic way to accomplish this task.

This could be an easy one, but all and any help would be greatly appreciated. (btw: I can handle the slicing, just need help with the positioning with css.)

[image: preview]
<sub>(source: [brocknunn.com](http://artjustice.brocknunn.com/q/nav.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you'd just need two slices and at least one containing div. So, if you're markup is like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav_ul">
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
        <li>Nav Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You actually have all you need. You then slice that image in two - the first slice is 90% of the width, and then the last 10% of the width (roughly - just enough to get the cap). You apply the first slice to the div, then the second to the ul. Sort of like this:

```
#nav {
   background-image: url(slice_left.jpg);
 }
.nav_ul {
   background-image: url(slice_right.jpg);
}
```

The thought being that the ul's background image will appear on top of it's containing div's background image.

You could even go back and edit the first slice (the long one) and clone the background for extra few 100 pixels, just in case your nav grows horizontally.

Comment: That is perfect, and it worked! Thank you guys for the help. Sometimes stepping away for a bit makes the difference. I was too close to it to even consider that solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for display: inline.

something along the lines of

```
#navbar { display: inline; }
<div id="navbar">
     <div id="right-image"><img src=rightimage></div>
     <div id="center-image"><img src=centerimage></div>
     <div id="left-image"><img src=leftimage></div>
</div>
```

You may have to mess with the margins a bit.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 border-image might work but it's not well supported.

In your case, you can create before and after pseudoelements and give them background images, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
<style type="text/css">
nav {
    position : relative;
    width : 600px;
    height : 89px;
    background : url(/q/nav.png) top center no-repeat;
    z-index : 1;
}
nav:before, nav:after {
    position:absolute;
    top : 0;
    width : 50px;
    height : 100%;
    z-index : 2;
    content : "";
}
nav:before {
    left : 0;
    background : url(/q/nav.png) top left no-repeat;
}
nav:after {
    right : 0;
    background : url(/q/nav.png) top right no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  whatever you need here properly positioned
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```